# Rails 5: Google Tag Manager will not fire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-tag-manager

I am using Google Tag Manager and it just stopped working on the landing page that client's are redirected to after filling out a form.  It works if you refresh the page, but doesn't work on redirects.

I know this smells like turbolinks, so I've modified the javascript function like so many articles have recommended:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(event) {
        console.log(event, dataLayer)
      var url = event.data.url;  
      dataLayer.push({
        'event':'pageView',
        'virtualUrl': url
      });
    });
    (function(w,d,s,l,i){
        console.log("getting it")
        w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({
            'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'
        });
        var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })

    (window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-######');
</script>
```

In my console, I see the `console.log(event, dataLayer)` but there is no request to: `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-######`

When I refresh the page, I see the same things logged to my console, but there IS a request to `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-######`.

Does anyone know how to make this request fire or understand what might be going wrong?